# Can I not have two ssh at the same time?

Tags: ssh

In two different terminals, I do

ssh -X root@ip_i

where i=1,2. One of them connects, the other fails with `ssh: connect to host ip_2 port 22: Connection refused`. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi,

You might go ahead on the existing terminal and you can right click it and choose duplicate session.

Comment: @vembutech What would that change? In both cases, a new bash session is started. There is no difference but in which window the session is displayed.

Comment: Can you connect to ip_2 when ip_1 is not connected? Is root login via ssh enabled on ip_2?

Comment: @souravc you were right. sorry, please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get does not mean you cannot run two ssh clients at the same time. Rather what it means is that one of the two IP addresses you connect to is not running an ssh server.

If you were to start the two ssh clients in opposite order, you could expect the first to fail and the second to succeed.

If both IP addresses happen to be assigned to the same server, it may be that that particular server has sshd listening on only one of the two IP addresses. By default sshd will listen on all your IP addresses, but by using `ListenAddress` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` it is possible to restrict sshd to only listen on some of the available IPs.

If there happen to be a firewall or other middlebox between client and server, then there are no limits to how strange behavior a misconfiguration could cause. So if that's the case, you may need to learn how to debug networking problems.